# Editing Wordpress Ajaxify Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, ajaxify

I have installed Ajaxify theme on my site (tekstyleankara.com). At the head of the it writes website's name on red background. I want to put the logo of the company there. How can I do that? Thanks.
I think I need to edit this line in **header.php** :

```
<div class="logo grid_2">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
</div>
```

But I couldn't find out what I should write instead. I made several attempts but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to edit your stylesheet Theme.css file. To find this file you need to go to your admin panel of wordpress. There you can click appearance at the right side of your page and click on the editor. There you see the file theme.css. You need to edit it and search the line `.logo`. From there you can change your red background with your logo.

Comment: There is no theme.css but there is style.css. But there is not .logo line there. This is the whole style.css :http://pastie.org/8253174